# Why I should not hard code sizes such as width,height,fontSize,padd,margin for responsive design in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, responsive-design

I thought like if I give width: 10, it will look the same in all devices since it occupied the same amount of area (because in 160dpi, 10dp = 10px, 320dpi 10dp = 20px but occupies same area in an inch)).I think my understanding is wrong. Share your thoughts on Responsive design and how to approach responsive font size as well. Thanks.

Comment: Can you follow this link `https://medium.com/@shanerudolfworktive/7-tips-to-develop-react-native-uis-for-all-screen-sizes-7ec5271be25c,` This will give an idea of how to handle with differnt screen size

Comment: Thanks but i have checked it.some hardcode value  was there entireScreenWidth / 380.why 380 is being used?

Comment: For native android, there is library called [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) for making dimensions responsive. For react-native, i think you can define height and width in %(not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive been through this phase , and thought similiar , but i was wrong. Sizes are different on different mobile so the best appraoch would be to actually calculate and make it in a percentage.

[react-native-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen) this is the library i use for actually making my app responsive and it worked out well. All you need is actually know your testing device height and width , suppose its 360*640.

Now you want to apply height of 200 , so basically you do `200/640 , i.e 31.25` ,
so in your view or whatever image you want you can add height by `height:hp('31.25%')`, and thats it, it adjust accordingly to devices.

And if you dont want to use any library , you can use Dimensions of react native.

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
var {deviceheight, devicewidth} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Now similiar approach , you now need to know resolution of your testing device and if its 360 * 640 , then you can do the same , just here suppose again height is 200 , then you have to do `height:0.3125*deviceheight`

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you have explained. One doubt, How to give responsive Font-Size?

Comment: same , like how you give height , and fontsize should be calculated on height. so suppose 24 works good in your phone, then 24/640 = 0.0375 , so ```fontSize:0.0375*deviceHeight```

Comment: and if you think the answer was helpful ,do upvote and mark as accepted so that it can help others. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `width: 10,`, `10` is equivalent to `10 units`. So in such cases, it will always set the with to 10 pixels, no matter which device/screen you use.

Instead, you can use percentage or relative measurements so that it can adapt to different devices, therefore, making your elements 'responsive'

Comment: Thanks.  One doubt, How to give responsive Font-Size?

Comment: My suggestion would be to check the device screen resolution/device type before page loading. There are a lot of libraries you can use for this. Once you get device size, you can set the Font-Size to a specific style from a pre-defined list. For example, you can make a list of styles for different resolutions, and at run time, set them at run time, depending on the screen/device size.